# insert a UTF-8 value into a SAP HANA database

Tags: php, utf-8, hana

I have tried for hours and cannot figure out how to insert a UTF-8 value into a SAP HANA database.

Is there some magic way to insert UTF-8 into HANA?

Instead of the actual UTF-8 string it inserts the utf8_encoded value 'å°èä¼æ¥­æéå¬å¸'.  But the string is already UTF-8.

```php
$conn=odbc_pconnect("Driver=/usr/sap/hdbclient/libodbcHDB.so;
ServerNode=$servernode;Database=$database;DriverUnicodeType=1", $username, $pass, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
$q="update mytable set native_name='專藝企業有限公司' where id=1234";
$ok=odbc_do($conn,$q);
```

Answer (score 0):

To store unicode characters, please change your Text column from varchar to NVARCHAR in the hana db and try. It should then work

Ref: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3290466

Comment: It was already set to nvarchar.  Could this is a PHP issue or an issue with the HANA ODBC driver?